# How to insert JSON data into a dynamic column MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json

Im simply trying to insert json data into a dynamic column.

Data looks like follows:

```
"{"Fields": {
    "CompanyCode": "1",
    "FiscalYear": "2014",
    "CalYear": "2014",
    "CalPeriod": "1",
    "MinPostDate": "2014-01-14T00:00:00",
    "MaxPostDate": "2014-01-14T00:00:00",
    "CreditDebitInd": "H"
  }
}"
```

Query is like this:

```
 INSERT INTO jsontest (ID, Text) VALUES(DEFAULT, 'JsonHere');
```

ID is an ID which is the PK and it auto increments.
Text is a BLOB

Comment: `For INSERT, REPLACE, and UPDATE, if a generated column is inserted into, replaced, or updated explicitly, the only permitted value is DEFAULT.`. See [13.1.18 CREATE TABLE Syntax :: CREATE TABLE and Generated Columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#create-table-generated-columns).

Comment: @wchiquito This literally has nothing to do with my question

Comment: When you talk about "dynamic column", you mean generated column? Otherwise, please add the structure of your table.

Comment: When I talk about a dynamic column, Im talking about a blob. I will update my question with the table structure now

Comment: What version of MySQL uses? Do you know [11.6 The JSON Data Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)?, it can be useful.

Comment: I am actually trying to use that now, I have posted another question. The JSON data type wont work

Comment: INSERT INTO jsontest (Text) VALUES('JsonHere');
If you did setup PK on ID correctly it will add the correct number by defualt

Comment: I know, im going to update my question. I found the answer

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES(DEFAULT, '{"Fields": {
    "CompanyCode": "E009",
    "FiscalYear": "2014",
    "CalYear": "2014",
    "CalPeriod": "1",
    "MinPostDate": "2014-01-14T00:00:00",
    "MaxPostDate": "2014-01-14T00:00:00",
    "CreditDebitInd": "H"
  }
}');
```

I was using the ` symbol to encapsulate the data. It needs to be the ' symbol